# Using a CASE expression inside the SELECT clause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having a great deal of difficulty replicating a result set with SQLAlchemy that I can generate with SQL. A big problem is I have difficulty comprehending the correct way to craft an ad-hoc column that can be inserted as an arg into query(). Another is that I've become confused between by the differences in purpose and implementation between the ORM and the Expression Language.

**Here are my models:**

```
class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    sz_shirt_dress_sleeve = db.relationship(
    'SizeKeyShirtDressSleeve', secondary=LinkUserSizeShirtDressSleeve, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

LinkUserSizeShirtDressSleeve = db.Table(
    'link_user_size_shirt_dress_sleeve',
    db.Column('size_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('size_key_shirt_dress_sleeve.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class SizeKeyShirtDressSleeve(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    size = db.Column(db.Numeric(4,2))
```

**I'm attempting to replicate this SQL:**

```
SELECT  
    size, 
    case    WHEN link_user_size_shirt_dress_sleeve.size_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS present
    FROM size_key_shirt_dress_sleeve 
    LEFT JOIN link_user_size_shirt_dress_sleeve
    ON size_key_shirt_dress_sleeve.id = link_user_size_shirt_dress_sleeve.size_id
;
```

**Things I've tried that haven't worked. (If you can infer any flawed thoughts when reading these, please point them out.)**

Setting up the `CASE` beforehand:

```
case = ([(LinkUserSizeShirtDressSleeve.c.size_id != None, True)], else_=False)

query = db.session.query(SizeKeyShirtDressSleeve.size, case)
    .outerjoin(LinkUserSizeShirtDressSleeve, SizeKeyShirtDressSleeve.id == LinkUserSizeShirtDressSleeve.size_id, )
    .filter(LinkUserSizeShirtDressSleeve.id == 1)
```

My python shell swears that there is a syntax error with the `else_=False`, even though I believe that's the same way [it's presented on the docs for case](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=case#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case):

```
>>> case = ([(LinkUserSizeShirtDressSleeve.c.size_id != None, True)], else_= False)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    case = ([(LinkUserSizeShirtDressSleeve.c.size_id != None, True)], else_= False)
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I omit the `else_`, and roll with this:

```
case = ([(LinkUserSizeShirtDressSleeve.c.size_id != None, True)])

query = db.session.query(SizeKeyShirtDressSleeve.size, case)
    .outerjoin(LinkUserSizeShirtDressSleeve, SizeKeyShirtDressSleeve.id == LinkUserSizeShirtDressSleeve.size_id, )
    .filter(LinkUserSizeShirtDressSleeve.id == 1)
```

I still error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/lirum/Envs/LTF-PhP3R-bs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 153, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lirum/Envs/LTF-PhP3R-bs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1399, in query
    return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lirum/Envs/LTF-PhP3R-bs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._set_entities(entities)
  File "/Users/lirum/Envs/LTF-PhP3R-bs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 149, in _set_entities
    entity_wrapper(self, ent)
  File "/Users/lirum/Envs/LTF-PhP3R-bs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3999, in __init__
    "expected - got '%r'" % (column, )
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '[(<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x10f633240>, True)]'
>>>
```

And I don't understand this error message either. Might this mean that I need to wrap the case in a `Column` or `column_literal` instance? I don't understand those well but I've seen them in the docs and the error hints that way. Although, god, I wish it would just take the case formation.

**Context for what I'm *trying* to do:**

I'm writing a view that will generate a page to list all of a User's sizes (sleeve, among others), AS WELL as all possible (sleeve) sizes (a user can be associated with multiple sizes). Possible sleeve sizes range from 30.0 to 38.0 and incrementing by 0.5. 
For example, say User with ID 1 is associated with sizes `30.0`, `30.5`, `31.0`, and `32.0`. Ultimately, a result set looking like this (headers unneeded):

```
Size        |   UserIsAssociated
--------|-------------------
30.0    |   True
30.5    |   True
31.0    |   True
31.5    |   False
32.0    |   True
32.5    |   False
33.0    |   False
...
38.0    |   False
```

Comment: `case` is a function, you should call it and assign the result to some none overlapping name: `has_size = case([(...)], else_=...)`. The latter error means that you can't pass a simple list of 2-tuple to `Query` as an entity.

Comment: Also if you're interested in fetching a boolean based on `size_id`, you don't need the case at all. Just use `LinkUserSizeShirtDressSleeve.c.size_id != None`.

Comment: ...right. case() is a _function_. Wow. And I didn't even need it to get the boolean. I think I have what I want. Thank you so much Ilja!

Answer (score -2):

I am not able to understand the question ...

I think you want to display the 'True' if Size id is not null else false

so write below query

select s.size,
case when s.size_id is null then 'False' else 'True' end as present
-- or it may be like
-- case when s.size_id is not null then 'True' else 'False' end as present
from size_key_shirt_dress_sleeve s
LEFT OUTER JOIN link_user_size_shirt_dress_sleeve m on m.id=s.size_id

or you can use isnull Method like

select s.size,
isnull(s.size_id,'False')
from size_key_shirt_dress_sleeve s
LEFT OUTER JOIN link_user_size_shirt_dress_sleeve m on m.id=s.size_id

I hope it will be work for you thanks!